Downloading a Printable version of IMDB.com Movie List
I'm a Newbie, in my 70's and certainly not very technical!
I have on IMDB.com a large Movie List - over 700! - and I would like to have a printed version so that I may refer to when choosing what movie to watch on my new smart TV!
Is there a simple way of doing this.
I can copy and paste directly from the Movie List but then I will have to spend a lot of time reformatting all the data.
What I am most intereted in getting is: The movie title, year, classification, the brief movie description and the DVD cover picture.
Is this achievable or am I asking for the impossible! Don't be afraid to call me an idiot! I'm thick skinned enough!!!
Thanks in advance
Philip1946
I've tried copy and pasting into word/excel but this will generate a large amount of effort to lick it into a reasonable shape!

I know that I can Export the movie list, but this comes without either the DVD cover or the brief decription...
